# Ruby pack('H*') equivalent in Python

Tags: python, ruby, pack, binascii

I'm having a hard time figuring out why outputs aren't the same. Notice that the difference is very tiny if you compare both `OUT`'s. What I'm trying to achieve is have the same output in Python to the one in Ruby.

**Ruby:**

`IN:['034151a3ec46b5670a682b0a63394f863587d1bc97483b1b6c70eb58e7f0aed192'].pack('H*')`

`OUT:\x03AQ\xA3\xECF\xB5g\nh+\nc9O\x865\x87\xD1\xBC\x97H;\elp\xEBX\xE7\xF0\xAE\xD1\x92`

**Python:**

`IN:unhexlify('034151a3ec46b5670a682b0a63394f863587d1bc97483b1b6c70eb58e7f0aed192')` `OUT:\x03AQ\xa3\xecF\xb5g\nh+\nc9O\x865\x87\xd1\xbc\x97H;\x1blp\xebX\xe7\xf0\xae\xd1\x92`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both languages have produced the same sequence of bytes; the only difference is in the way they display those bytes to you. Ruby has an `\e` string escape sequence for the `1b` byte (ASCII ESC, escape), while Python displays that byte as `\x1b`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is very old, but I had the exact same trouble where a ruby 'pack'ed sha1 was being stored to a mongodb field, and trying to read it in using the pymongo find function produced something that seemed unreadable at first.

I solved it not using hexlify, but just using the binascii binary to ascii decoder (which itself still generates a 28-byte long binary), and then using base64 decode and traditional hexing:

```
new_sha1= base64.b64decode(binascii.b2a_base64(agg_sha1, newline=False)).hex()
```

I double-checked that it generated the correct sha1 by searching in the mongo shell afterwards.  Finding the answer was a miracle, and I hope this helps someone else demystify 'pack'.

*Edited to add* - found out binascii can do even better with the b2a_hex function!

```
new_sha1= binascii.b2a_hex(sha1)
```

So as long as you're using .pack('H*') this should work